# Proving the inquality $\int_{0}^{\infty} f^\lambda(t)d(t^\lambda) \le \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)dt\right)^\lambda$ for $\lambda\ge 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

I am actually reading an article where the authors used the following 
whithout mentioning any proof of it
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f^\lambda(t)d(t^\lambda) \le \lambda\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\int_0^t f(\tau)d\tau\right)^{\lambda -1}f(t) dt =  \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)dt\right)^\lambda $$

Where $\lambda\ge 1$, the expression $d(t^\lambda)$ stand for $\lambda t^{\lambda-1}dt$  and the function $f$ is a nonnegative **nonincreasing** and integrable function on $(0,\infty).$

> My first Guess is that this inequality must be related to some convex inequalities (which I do not know): Because **for $\lambda\ge 1$ the function $x\mapsto x^\lambda$ is convex** and this function is very linked to this problem.

Now the equality 
$$\lambda\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\int_0^t f(\tau)d\tau\right)^{\lambda -1}f(t) dt =  \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)dt\right)^\lambda $$
is rather easy to check since by setting 
$$F(t) = \int_0^t f(\tau)d\tau$$

we end up with

$$\lambda\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\int_0^t f(\tau)d\tau\right)^{\lambda -1}f(t) dt = \lambda\int_{0}^{\infty} F(t)^{\lambda -1}F'(t) dt \\= F^\lambda(\infty)-F^\lambda(0)=  \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)dt\right)^\lambda $$

Any reference, idea,  help or proposal is very welcome.

Comment: This first displayed equation is reminiscent of [Minkowski's integral inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski.27s_integral_inequality)

Comment: sorry but I don't figure out the relation of this with Minkowski inequality

Comment: I dont undersatnd why the limsup is not 0

Comment: The  first terms of the average are $S_1 = 1/1,S_2= 0/2, S_3 = -1/3,S_4 =0/4,S_5= 1/5,S_6=2/6, S_7 =3/7$ and this clearly converges to 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ is non-increasing, we have

$$\int_0^t f(\tau) \, d\tau \geq \int_0^t f(t) \, d\tau = t f(t).$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align*} \int_0^{\infty} f^{\lambda}(t) \, d(t^{\lambda}) &= \lambda \int_0^{\infty} (t f(t))^{\lambda-1} f(t) \, dt \\ &\leq \lambda \int_0^{\infty} \left( \int_0^t f(\tau) \, d\tau \right)^{\lambda-1} f(t) \, dt. \end{align*}$$

---

The following example shows that the monotonicity of $f$ is a crucial assumption.

**Example:** Consider

$$f(t) := 1_{[1,2]}(t),$$

then

$$\int_0^{\infty} f^{\lambda}(t) \, d(t^{\lambda}) = \bigg[t^{\lambda} \bigg]_{t=1}^{2} = 2^{\lambda}-1$$

and

$$\left( \int_0^{\infty} f(t) \, dt \right)^{\lambda} = 1^{\lambda} = 1;$$

therefore we have

$$\int_0^{\infty} f^{\lambda}(t) \, d(t^{\lambda}) =2^{\lambda}-1>1 = \left( \int_0^{\infty} f(t) \, dt \right)^{\lambda} \qquad \text{for all $\lambda>1$}.$$

Comment: thanks I have forgotten one of the crucial assumption . $f$ is also a nonincreasing function I fixed it. sorry for the misleading

Comment: @GuyFsone See my edited answer.

Comment: ok but in (0,2) your function increase isn't?

Comment: @GuyFsone Well, yes... if you prefer, you can ignore the second part of my answer. The first part answers your question.

Comment: thank that was blatantly obvious . I feel shameless and ridiculous. Hahaha maybe I am tired I should have some rest. thanks